How to Set Up Azure AD Login on GUI-Enabled Ubuntu VM?
I'm trying to set up Azure AD authentication on an Ubuntu VM that has a graphical user interface (GUI) enabled. I have successfully installed the AADSSHLoginForLinux extension and can log in using SSH with my Azure AD credentials. However, after setting up the GUI (using xfce/LightDM), I encounter a blank screen after entering my Azure AD credentials.
Any help?

To join Ubuntu VM with AD, create a VM and while setting it up, on the management tab of the VM creation page, check the "Login with Microsoft Entra ID" option.

Ensure that the users who need to log in are assigned the "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" or "Virtual Machine User Login" roles under the VM's access control (IAM) settings.

Once the VM is created, use the Azure portal to get the VM's public IP address and use an SSH client to connect:
Update and Upgrade Packages
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y

Install XFCE / LightDM
sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies lightdm -y
sudo systemctl enable lightdm


Reboot once installed and re-login
then  install Remote Desktop (Xrdp) on Ubuntu 18.04 | E2E Networks documentation
and allow 3389 port in your VM and NSG and restart the xrdp application. Relogin using azure AD creds here-

Done. You should be able to set up Azure AD login on a GUI-enabled Ubuntu VM. Note it takes some time to load up.

reference-

GUI on Ubuntu
Ubuntu with XFCE
Enable graphical remote desktop for Linux virtual machines in Azure Lab Services
Integrate with Azure Active Directory


haha amazing UI for ubuntu
